# MT4 sends multiple outdated emails

Tags: email, mt4

My EA is set up to send an email when a trade is initiated. Over time the standard body of the email has been changed & improved upon.

However, on forward testing my EA, it spurts out older versions of the trade notification email I designed (v8.16) - even though it shouldn't be doing this - alongside emails from the updated version (v8.17) - which is what it should be doing.

It's as if I have another MT4 account somewhere running an older version of my EA, but I don't.

- I don't have any older versions running in my VPS.
- I don't have any EA's running on my local desktop either
- As you can see, they are from the same trade (as seen on the matching ticket number) as well as the same entry price. Surely if I was running two accounts the ticket numbers wouldn't match.

Has anyone else had any issues around this strange "phenomena"

---

[image: Screenshot of MT4 Email setup.]

> An example of a discontinued (v8.16), but still arriving form:
>   [image: This is the old version]

---

> An example of an updated (v8.17) form:
>   [image: This is the new version of the notification email]

Comment: **Q1:** Why do you think, it were a **[ [tag:php] ]**-related error? **Q2:** Where does your SMTP-host reside? Is it inside your VPS / VPN, or is it an externally provisioned service, **outside of your domain-of-control?** **Q3:** Which type of VPS service do you use for the [ SuT ] operations -- an FX-Broker-provisioned VPS, or some other, from a public, globally available VPS/hosting-provider, that you have on your own decided to choose and use for this [ SuT ] Project testing?

Comment: 1) Not sure why I tagged PHP in the question, please disregard. 2 & 3) it's a broker-provided VPS in partnership with Beeks financial. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Todd, could you kindly yet address the **Q2? What SMTP-server does your MT4 send each message to?** A [**PrintScreen**] of the MT4 **setup page** would help a lot in this, wouldn't it?**

Comment: Yes, question has been updated and added screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given the above clarifications, the most straightforward way to **avoid any *"un-authorised"* binary-replicated instances of your VPS-hosted image** to access any longer your SMTP-entry point ( where the "*discontinued*" version(s) of email forms have left the smoke-trail fingerprints, demonstrated by a suspect / replicated operations still sending discontinued v8.16-forms ) would be:

- **now `(!)`** immediately change your SMTP-service password
- **add** **`MQL4`** self-reporting WatchDOG evidence collecting emails, pushing such WatchDOG from each visit into **`OnInit()`** / **`OnDeinit()`** handlers, reporting **`AccountInfo()`** details, incl. the details as is a hostname, IP address of the host and a localhost's **`tracroute`**-output to some known, public reference point.

Comment: Yes this sound you're onto something here, I do have older inactive versions of the EA on my local system which I've now deleted. One inactive version is on my VPS but the system won't let me delete it. This does carry the older version of the email body but isn't tied to any chart or platform. What's WatchDOG anyway? Thanks

Comment: WatchDOG is a concept of looking after some events, state-transitions or just time-flow. WatchDOG reports any such monitored entity to some central repository of events, usually well-stamped with some ordinal-UUID or just high-resolution time stamp ( [us] or [ns], to disambiguate SEQ-of-events ).

Comment: Ok sounds good. I'll take your input to my broker customer services - they're a good team there - as well as Beeks as most of this is now outside my area of knowledge but I'll start with changing my smtp password. Many thanks :)

Comment: + Have seen a lot of VPS add-ons on FX Broker service. Not always a professional grade ones. Do you have a Broker/VPS-provider independent cryptography protection of the VPS-access? Some sort of SSH-tunnel to an independent sshd on a hosted host, that is fully & exclusively under your domain of control ( including ssh-key management )? If not, the service is vulnerable, irrespective of what Broker / VPS-provider Reps. are saying. ***Beware Greeks, if they bring gifts to you ....*** :o)